# Robocopy a specific folder

Tags: robocopy

We use a folder template for our projects we work on and my normal process to log each job is to right click, copy, rename, make shortcuts, etc... It's like a 5 minute process after everything is said and done. For right now the idea is to just copy that template folder, rename, make shortcuts, and send those shortcuts to the appropriate directories. This issue I'm having is that when I run robocopy it is copying the contents and not the template directory itself. A snippet of what I have right now is:

```
robocopy \\Users\blah\blah\DirectoryIWantToCopy \\Users\blah\blah\CopiedDirectory /e
```

As of right now when I run it, it is copying everything inside the directory instead of just copying the parent directory. I understand why it's doing it, but it seems as though the only way to accomplish what I'm doing is to exclude all the directories inside \Users\blah\blah\ that I don't want it to copy. Is there not a switch to add that just says copy this specific directory and all sub directories of this specific directory? I'm sure that is as simple as it sounds, and I'm sure I'm overlooking it, but from all the other questions I've googled I haven't been able to find an answer that answers this.

Answer (score 0):

So when I read the information about the switches on Technet it kept referencing a file, and thought that only meant an actual file and not a directory. I got it to work by simply adding the file name after the destination. Thanks.